# Class _PathPoint and Class _PointQueue error without use any pods. Just click on textField in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I have a TextField on a View. Getting below warning on tapping of a text field. Not sure Why? Below is the code used.

This is view where button is available to click. On click of this button, Bottom view will be displayed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cardShown = false
    @State var cardDismissal = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Button(action: {
                    cardShown.toggle()
                    cardDismissal.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Show Card")
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                })
                BottomCard(cardShown: $cardShown, cardDismissal: $cardDismissal, height: 400, content: {
                    CardContent()
                        .padding()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the bottom view where the text field exists. On this text field click, getting error.

```
struct CardContent: View {
    
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("Photo Collage")
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .padding()
            
            Text("You can create awesome photo grids and share them with all of your friends")
                .font(.system(size: 18))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .frame(height: 100)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Generic View.

```
struct BottomCard<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    @Binding var cardShown: Bool
    @Binding var cardDismissal: Bool
    let height: CGFloat
    init(cardShown: Binding<Bool>, cardDismissal: Binding<Bool>, height: CGFloat, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        _cardShown = cardShown
        _cardDismissal = cardDismissal
        self.height = height
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Dimmed
            GeometryReader { _ in
                EmptyView()
            }
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
            .opacity(cardShown ? 1: 0)
            .animation(Animation.easeIn, value: 0.9)
            
            .onTapGesture {
                // Dismiss
                dismiss()
            }
            
            // Card
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                  content
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        // Dismiss
                        dismiss()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Dismiss")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, height: 50)
                            .background(Color.pink)
                            .cornerRadius(8)

                    })
                     .padding()
                }
                //.background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .frame(height: height)
                .offset(y: (cardShown && cardShown) ? 0 : 800)
                .animation(Animation.default.delay(0.2), value: 0.2)
                .padding(.bottom, 300)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
    
    func dismiss() {
        cardDismissal.toggle()
        //self.view.endEditing(true)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.25){
            cardShown.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Getting below error while tapping on textField.

```
objc[9303]: Class _PointQueue is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x129df7a50) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x13c7b68d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.


objc[9303]: Class _PathPoint is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x129df7a78) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x13c7b68b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. You’ll likely find the answer as you create one.

Comment: I have edited this post. please check.

Comment: I am getting this same message but, for me, it appears to happen (only once) when I use the keyboard, i.e. pressing the command key in prep to rotate the simulator. I am NOT getting the error when testing on a device. Have you tried running on a device?

Comment: No, I tried it on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for an answer on this and it appears it could just be 'log noise'. I found the following in a different question.

Apple developer Quinn “The Eskimo!” @ Developer Technical Support @ Apple answered this question [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691361):

> This is not an error per se. Rather, it’s the Objective-C runtime
> telling you that:
>
> - Two frameworks within your process implement the same class (well, in
>   this case classes, namely _PathPoint and _PointQueue).
> - The runtime will use one of them, choosing it in an unspecified way.
>
> This can be bad but in this case it’s not. Both of the implementations
> are coming from the system (well, the simulated system) and thus you’d
> expect them to be in sync and thus it doesn’t matter which one the
> runtime uses.
>
> So, in this specific case, these log messages are just [log noise](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115461).